# Detect drop target with HammerJS

Tags: drag-and-drop, hammer.js

I'm using HammerJS to abstract drag, scale and rotate for desktop and mobile. All I'm missing  is drop. How do I define an element as a drop target that throws an event when another element is dragged over or dropped onto it? Something like jQueryUI's [droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/) that will work with HammerJS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just solved that today.

On dropping object, set a global "look for me" flag. and then setTimeout() to shortly (say 30ms) set it back to false.
Hide (and move) the dropped object, putting it back after a short time allowing the onMouseOver and onMouseOut events to trigger on the drop target object.

Watch those events for the "look for me" flag.

I haven't really tried it much yet.

(My first post.)

Comment: Great first post! Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

The only one fast way for detect drop target element is to use

`document.elementFromPoint`

Like this:

```
function dragEnd($event){
    var targetEl = document.elementFromPoint($event.gesture.center.pageX, $event.gesture.center.pageX);

    your code
}
```